# why doesn't next-auth jwt callback get called on page transitions?

Tags: javascript, authentication, jwt, next.js, next-auth

I'm using next-auth `Credentials` provider to implement authentication in my next js application with a custom django backend.

Here is my jwt callback:

```
async jwt(token, user, account) {
    if (user && account) {
      // The user has just logged in.
      const decoded = jwt_decode(user.access)
      token.accessToken = user.access
      token.refreshToken = user.refresh
      token.accessTokenExpires = decoded.exp
      return token
    }
    if ((Date.now() + 15 * 1000) <= (token.accessTokenExpires * 1000)) {
      // The user has logged in before but the token.accessToken has not been expired.
      return token
    }
    // token.accessToken is expired and we need to get a new jwt using token.refreshToken.
    const newJwt = await refreshJwt(token.refreshToken)
    if (newJwt) {
      token.accessToken = newJwt
      const decoded = jwt_decode(newJwt)
      token.accessTokenExpires = decoded.exp
      return token
    }
    // token.accessToken and token.refreshToken are both expired.
    return {}
}
```

This is the problem:

After jwt(`token.accessToken`) expires, the `jwt callback` won't get called. So it cannot refresh the jwt(`token.accessToken`).

But when I refresh the page manually (hard refresh), it gets called and properly sets the new jwt(`token.accessToken`) using the `token.refreshToken`.

It also gets called and properly sets the new jwt when user changes tabs on his/her browser.

I want the `jwt callback` to get called every time I use the hook `useSession`. (I use `useSession` in all of my pages, both server-side rendered pages and statically-generated pages).

Comment: do you have the full providers code? Could be super usefull if you can share it to help other developers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fixed the problem by passing options to `next-auth/client`'s `Provider` in `_app.js`:

```
return (
    <Provider session={session}
              options={{clientMaxAge: TIME_INTERVAL_IN_SECONDS_WHICH_HAS_TO_BE_LESS_THAN_JWT_EXPIRATION_TIME}} >
        ...
    </Provider>
)
```

---

for v4, the option is replaced by [**refetchInterval**](https://next-auth.js.org/getting-started/upgrade-v4#sessionprovider), so it should be as follow:

```
return (
    <SessionProvider session={session} refetchInterval={TIME_INTERVAL_IN_SECONDS_WHICH_HAS_TO_BE_LESS_THAN_JWT_EXPIRATION_TIME}>
        <Component {...pageProps} />
    </SessionProvider>
)
```